# How to bypass the verification code when run test case from Selenium script?

Tags: test-automation, selenium

I want to run my test case with Selenium script. But whenever I login with selenium it aways ask for verification code. I know I can do it using the Profile Id, but I want to do it with code. Something like we manually do once once we enter the password, and after that the platform doesn't ask for the verification code.

I tried below code:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities doc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        doc.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(doc);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test@testing.com");

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Qwerty@12345");
        File file = new File("Cookies.data");
        try     
        {     
            // Delete old file if exists
            file.delete();      
            file.createNewFile();           
            FileWriter fileWrite = new FileWriter(file);                            
            BufferedWriter Bwrite = new BufferedWriter(fileWrite);                          
            // loop for getting the cookie information      

            // loop for getting the cookie information      
            for(Cookie ck : driver.manage().getCookies())                           
            {           
                Bwrite.write((ck.getName()+";"+ck.getValue()+";"+ck.getDomain()+";"+ck.getPath()+";"+ck.getExpiry()+";"+ck.isSecure()));                                                                                                    
                Bwrite.newLine();             
            }           
            Bwrite.close();         
            fileWrite.close();  

        }
        catch(Exception ex)                 
        {       
            ex.printStackTrace();           
        }
        ...
```

Afer this I creted a new class and then set this cookie on it, like this:

```
...
try {
    File file = new File("Cookies.data");                           
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);                           
    BufferedReader Buffreader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);                         
    String strline;         
    while((strline=Buffreader.readLine())!=null){
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(strline,";");
        while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
            String name = token.nextToken();                    
            String value = token.nextToken();                   
            String domain = token.nextToken();                  
            String path = token.nextToken();                    
            Date expiry = null;                 

            String val;         
            if(!(val=token.nextToken()).equals("null"))
            {       
                expiry = new Date(val);                 
            }       
            Boolean isSecure = new Boolean(token.nextToken()).                              
            booleanValue();     
            Cookie ck = new Cookie(name,value,domain,path,expiry,isSecure);         
            System.out.println(ck);
            driver.manage().addCookie(ck); // This will add the stored cookie to your current session                   
        }       
    }       
}catch(Exception ex){                   
    ex.printStackTrace();           
}       
driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");
...
```

I am not sure wether this is correct or not because I am trying this for the 1st time. I took the reference from this link:

```
https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html
```

Please help me to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you can disable the verification on the user's profile. It is under `Setup > Profiles > General User Permissions`, called "Two-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins".

Be careful with this, not to disable it for your administrator profile. I'd recommend to clone the administrator profile, and remove some permissions from it.

If you don't want to change the profile permission, you can also whitelist the IP address that is accessing the platform.

Sources:

- https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000ZrhqQAC
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_networkaccess.htm&type=5

Comment: but i want to do it with code,i don't want to do from admin level,what i want is that two step verfication didn't get disabled but if someone already has logging then it save their detail and don't ask again as it work when we logged in fromUI.

Comment: Then don't close the Selenium session when running your tests. Just logout, don't close the test, then log in again. Please take a look at Selenium's documentation if you can login "as a setup procedure", and then run your tests with the same credentials, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not familiar with java (thus not selenium with java as well). How does your selenium login? 
I am tinkering with something similar and I find it rather useful to bypass login using sfdx-cli i.e.by using  `sfdx force:org:open -r` with inside automation itself (which returns an url in command output) and access lorg just as a website.